# wso2 identity server - password policies

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 identity server support password policies like password ageing?  I couldn't see anything relating to these features on the wso2 web site, or the identity server data sheet.

If not, is this functionality on the roadmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define limited set of restrictions such as length, allowed characters etc in the user-mgt.xml using the "PasswordJavaScriptRegEx" property. But this is applied to the front end.

Other than that the WSO2 Identity Server has not defined any password policies, it rather depends on the underlying user store's password policies. For example with the Active Directory as the user store, the WSO2 Identity Server inherits the password policy defined in the Active Directory DC.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, from a brief investigation, [OpenDJ](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/configref/password-policy.html) seems to have more features regarding password policy than [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/account-and-password-policy-management.html).  I'll investigate further...

Answer (score 1):

With WSO2 IS 4.5.0 , IS admin can define custom password policies and enforce them at user creation. Please refer the product documentation.

Comment: Do you have a link to the relevant section in the product documentation?

Comment: Please refer following link https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Password+Policies

Comment: Hmm. So this does not address password aging (only the allowed characters as per Suresh's answer), right?

Answer (score 0):

According to WSO2-IS they cannot directly support for this feature, hopefully in the future. If you use a Secondary User Store like LDAP we can customize this requirement, but also it depend on the LDAP type.

But as a policy, you cannot find any feature upto WSO2-IS 5.1.0 for the password ageing.

Hope this may help you.